# WCF service don't send a message request to a server in Windows XP SP3

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-xp-sp3

I have a WCF client/server app. All services work perfectly in Windows 7, but one small service do not send a message request to the server in Windows XP SP3. 
I found a IEnumerable collection and a byte array of service's method are the reason of the problem. 
Is it really Windows XP cannot serialize these types of data?

Comment: Does your Windows XP have necesary .net framework? What enpoint are you using?

Comment: Maybe you do not have correct .net framework version? Please add more details. What kind of error you getting? How your service look like?

Comment: I use .Net 4.0 (full profile). 

I define a endpoint for the service by using protocol WsHttpBinding. WCF diagnostics tracing show me that error I get has description like "Failed to send request message over http" with no details. If I remove a IEnumerable collection and a byte array from a data contract, the service sends successfully a message request.

Comment: The IEnumerable collection is a variable defined in the return type of service's method. The byte array is defined in the class passed as parameter of the method.

Also other methods of the service work correctly. They don't use collections or arrays.